# split a field having comma separated values and update the same field by adding additional rows with separated values

Tags: mysql

I have a field with comma separated values.I want to split the field and add the rows with the obtained values(after splitting) in the same table.

Eg:

```
**Data as in db**
ID   CustomerId   Preferences
------------------------------

 1.   4456823          AA,BB,DD
 2.   4456824          BB,DD
```

---

```
**Data format required**

ID   CustomerId   Preferences
------------------------------
1.    4456823          AA
2.    4456823          BB
3.    4456823          DD
4.    4456824          BB
5.    4456824          DD
```

Is there a way I can do this without using a temp table because the the **Customer** here is a cascading entity..This Id is formed by some other table which is an auto increment key.

Basically I want to update the first field and insert the other split values to get the desired result shown above

Comment: Dare we ask why you have a table with comma separated values? :-(

Comment: Data migration !!!:>

Comment: OK. And just to confirm - the id of the source and the id of the target need have no relation to each other?

Comment: No..That's an auto increment key...Here the source and target table are same

Comment: OK. I still don't understand why 'using a temp table' conflicts with 'cascading entity'

Comment: Can I use a temp table and then update the record for the first split value and insert for the other split values?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using a table of integers (0-9):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,customerid INT NOT NULL
,preferences VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,4456823,'AA,BB,DD'),
(2,4456824,'BB,DD');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_new_table;

CREATE TABLE my_new_table (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,customerid INT NOT NULL,preferences CHAR(2) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_new_table (customerid,preferences) 
SELECT DISTINCT customerid, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(preferences,',',i+1),',',-1) x FROM my_table, ints ORDER BY customerid,x;

SELECT * FROM my_new_table;
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | customerid | preferences |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 |    4456823 | AA          |
|  2 |    4456823 | BB          |
|  3 |    4456823 | DD          |
|  4 |    4456824 | BB          |
|  5 |    4456824 | DD          |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Good one..but I want to update and insert in the same table..Is there a possibility of doing that?

Comment: No (or not easily). But obviously you can delete your old table and rename your new one.

Comment: That table is live(In production) !!!..I cannot delete it..  Or if there is other workaround